# How to assign data for property of class after get data from Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a problem when assign data from Postgres
this my snippet:

```
var database = function () {
    client.connect(function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.error('could not connect to postgres', err);
        }
    });
};

database.prototype.getData = function() {
    this.data = [];
    this.queryStr = 'SELECT * FROM "agents"';
    this.query = client.query(this.queryStr);
    var data = [];
    this.query.on('row', function(row) {
        data.push(row);
        //console.log(data); // get data successfully 
    });

    //could not assign data
    console.log(data); // but when go out above function, data become no value
    this.data = data; // and then I can not assign it for property of class (like this.data)
};
```

Could anyone help me to resolve this.sorry my English. Tks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is assigned inside a callback which is executed after your method has run.

Usually you would pass a callback function when execution of your function is over.

I'm not skilled at using postgre library, but here's a pseudo-code:

```
database.prototype.getData = function(success) {
    this.data = [];
    this.queryStr = 'SELECT * FROM "agents"';
    this.query = client.query(this.queryStr);
    var self = this;
    var data = [];
    this.query.on('row', function(row) {
        data.push(row);
        //console.log(data); // get data successfully 
    });
    this.query.on('end', function() { //when the query executes succesfully
        self.data = data;
        success(); //call success callback or perform other actions 
    });
};
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it still not have value when outside function.
actually it is .on('end', function).

Comment: It will not have the value outside of it in any case

Comment: But I want to it assign to class property, so I can use that data throught that Object.

Comment: You can assign it in the function. You can see it in m ycode

Comment: I do the same your code, but I when I access database.data, it's not a value